# why is stack and heap both required for memory allocation

Tags: memory, dynamic, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've searched a while but no conclusive answer is present on why value types have to be allotted on the stack while the reference types i.e. dynamic memory or the objects have to reside on the heap.
why cannot the same be alloted on the stack?

Answer (score 4):

They can be.  In practice they're not because stack is a typically scarcer resource than heap and allocating reference types on the stack may exhaust it quickly.  Further, if a function returns data allocated on its stack, it will require copying semantics on the caller's part or risk returning something that will be overwritten by the next function call.

Value types, typically local variables, can be brought in and out of scope quickly and easily with native machine instructions.  Copy semantics for value types on return is trivial as most fit into machine registers.  This happens often and should be as cheap as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct that value types always live on the stack. Read Jon Skeet's article on the topic:

> **[Memory in .NET - what goes where](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html)**

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the *stack* paradigm (nested allocations/deallocations) cannot handle certain algorithms which need non-nested object lifetimes.

just as the *static allocation* paradigm cannot handle recursive procedure calls. (e.g. naive calculation of fibonacci(n) as f(n-1) + f(n-2))

I'm not aware of a simple algorithm that would illustrate this fact though. any suggestions would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are allocated in the stack. If that was not the case, you wouldn't be able to have variables pointing to the heap when allocating variable's memory. You CAN allocate things in the stack if you want, just create a buffer big enough locally and manage it yourself.

Comment: So basically your are making a custom managed heap on your stack. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Anything a method puts on the stack will vanish when the method exits.  In .net and Java, it would be perfectly acceptable (in fact desirable) if a class object vanished as soon as the last reference to it vanished, but it would be fatal for an object to vanish while references to it still exist.  It is not in the general case possible for the compiler to know, when a method creates an object, whether any references to that object will continue to exist after the method exits.  Absent such assurance, the only safe way to allocate class objects is to store them on the heap.

Incidentally, in .net, one major advantage of mutable value types is that they can be passed by reference without surrendering perpetual control over them.  If class 'foo', or a method thereof, has a structure 'boz' which one of foo's methods passes by reference to method 'bar', it is possible for bar, or the methods it calls, to do whatever they want to 'boz' until they return, but once 'bar' returns any references it held to 'boz' will be gone.  This often leads to much safer and cleaner semantics than the promiscuously-sharable references used for class objects.